# ¿Cómo comparar 2 cadenas pero no completas? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Necesito comparar 2 cadenas, los primeros 4 caracteres de: **cadena1** frente a todos los caracteres de **cadena2** (siempre son 4).

Podría hacerlo con for, pero creo que es mas eficiente usar alguna función ya creada.

Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: 2 cadenas... `string`, `char[]`, `char*`, `wstring`, `wchar[]`, `wchar*`, `QString` ¿¿?? ¿Qué has probado hasta la fecha? ¿En serio te preocupa la eficiencia a la hora de hacer 4 comparaciones de caracteres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [`std::string::find`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). Esa función te permite buscar una cadena dentro de otra, en caso de dar con ella devuelve la posición y en caso contrario devuelve [`std::string::npos`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos).

Para comparar una sub-cadena en lugar de la cadena completa, usa [`std::string::substr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
std::string cadena1 = "cadena1";
std::string cadena2 = "esto es otra cadena";

std::cout << "Las primeras 4 letras de " << cadena1
          << " se encuentran en la posición "
          << cadena2.find(cadena1.substr(0, 4))
          << " de la cadena " << cadena2 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una `substring` de los primeros 4 caracteres de la cadena larga, y comparar la `substring` con la cadena que siempre contiene 4 caracteres:

```
std::string str = "123456789abc";
std::string primeros_cuatro = str.substr(0, 4);
```

Y luego hacer una comparación:

```
if(!string1.compare(string2)
    //hacer algo
```